# Using MKOverlayRenderer in iOS7 to display UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, mkoverlay

I am trying to display a UIImage as a overlay for a map-based iPad application. I attempted to follow the 4 steps to setting a custom overlay defined in Apple's documentation: define the overlay data object, define the object renderer, implement the map view in map view delegate, and add overlay data object to to map view. After attempting to do all these, there is no overlay when I run the simulator. Any advice would be fantastic. My code is as follows

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "bjorkOverlay.h"
#import "bjorkOverlayRenderer.h"

@interface TUTViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *location;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic) MKCoordinateRegion region;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapRect boundingMapRect;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D bjorkOverlayCenterPoint;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapRect bjorkOverlayBoundingMapRect;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "TUTViewController.h"
#import "bjorkOverlay.h"
#import "bjorkOverlayRenderer.h"
@import MapKit;

@interface TUTViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation TUTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    _mapView.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(  45.022943             ,-87.146606);
    MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerLeftCoord);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D upperRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 45.048513, -87.124765);
    MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperRightCoord);
    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);

    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapRect animated:YES];

    bjorkOverlay * mapOverlay = [[bjorkOverlay alloc] init];
    [_mapView addOverlay:mapOverlay];

}



- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:        (id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MKOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay = [[MKOverlayRenderer alloc] init];
    return mapOverlay;
}



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@end
```

bjorkOverlay.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import MapKit;

@interface bjorkOverlay : NSObject <MKOverlay>

+ (id)overlayWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D bjorkOverlayCenterPoint;

@property (nonatomic) MKMapRect bjorkOverlayBoundingMapRect;


@end
```

bjorkOverlay.m

```
#import "bjorkOverlay.h"
@import MapKit;

@implementation bjorkOverlay 

 + (id)overlayWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate radius:(CLLocationDistance)radius{
    bjorkOverlay* overlay = [[bjorkOverlay alloc] init];
    overlay.coordinate = coordinate;
    return overlay;
}

-(MKMapRect)boundingMapRect{
CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(  45.022943 ,-87.146606);
    MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerLeftCoord);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D upperRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 45.048513, -87.124765);
    MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperRightCoord);
    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);

    return mapRect;
}


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)bjorkOverlayCenterPoint
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = {
    45.035728,-87.1356855
    };

    return coord1;
}

@end
```

bjorkOverlayRenderer.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface bjorkOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer

@end
```

bjorkOverlayRender.m

```
#import "bjorkOverlayRenderer.h"

@implementation bjorkOverlayRenderer

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"];

    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];
    CGRect clipRect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];

    CGContextAddRect(ctx, clipRect);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, theRect, imageReference);



}


@end
```

Any advice would be great or if you have seen sample code for MKOverlayRenderer I would appreciate a link. Thanks

Comment: In `rendererForOverlay`, code is creating a `MKOverlayRenderer` (the base class which draws essentially nothing).  Shouldn't the code be creating a `bjorkOverlayRenderer` instead?  Eg. `bjorkOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay = [[bjorkOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];`

Comment: Thank you @Anna for the suggestion. I believe you are correct however even after I changed `MKOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay = [[MKOverlayRenderer alloc] init]` with `bjorkOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay = [[bjorkOverlayRenderer alloc] init]` in ViewController.m - it did not add the overlay. I don't need to do anything with Interface Builder correct? Or anything in the MKMapViewDelegate? My image file is saved in the images.xcassets folder. Thanks again for your suggestion! I appreciate it

Comment: Make sure you call `initWithOverlay` (not just `init`).  In IB, check that the map view is connected to the mapView outlet in the view controller.  You'll have to do some debugging to make sure all the code written actually executes and that variables have the value you expect, etc.  Besides checking the outlet, also check that the image filename exactly matches the asset including upper/lower case.